# MySQL - Mac - Error 2002 - Can't connect to local... through socket

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2002

I had MySQL running fine on my Mac till earlier today when I installed homebrew and also updated my Path.

When I try to run mysql from my ternimal window now, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can't connect MySQLAdmin either.

I can't even run Mysqld.  The error I get when trying to run mysqld is that it can't create test file.

I also tried to telnet localhost 3306 and wasn't able to connect.

Any help would be appreciated as I am fairly new to Mac.

Comment: You should try asking this on http://superuser.com

Comment: What does your config file look like? Can you post the contents of your config file? The file is `my.cnf` and found in `/etc/`. When I had this problem, I renamed the config file and restarted the computer... things seemed to work better. Have you messed with the config file at all?

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem? If yes could you just accept one of them then?

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij - This question is from 6 years ago.  I was fairly new to stackoverflow back then and unfortunately didn't mark the appropriate answer.  I don't recall which answer helped me solve my problem.  I suggest start by using the answers that have received the most amount of votes by fellow users.

Answer (score 12):

If it's homebrew installation try:

```
$ mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 8):

Basically, all you have to do is:

1. Go to "System Preferences"
2. Then, if MySQL is installed you should see a "MySQL" icon in the "Other" section right at the bottom. Click on it.
   [image: mac system preferences]
3. Click on "Start MySQL Server"
   [image: mysql panel]

You will now be able to start the MySQL command prompt without getting the "Can't connect..." error.

Answer (score 4):

The mysql error (2002) is caused by the fact mysqld isn't running.  The error you are seeing when starting mysqld is probably a permissions issue.  Try starting mysqld as root or sudo'ing the command.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm user of osX 10.11.3 (El Capitan)*

1. first of all, check your mysql version.

   ```
   $ mysql --version
   ```
2. check the server is already running.

   ```
   $ ps -ex | grep mysql
   ```

   If you checked this following string, that means mysql server is already running.

   => mysqld_safe  /  --pid-file=#{path}

   (The mysql pid file created when mysql server running to succeessfully. )

   In that case, you have to stop mysql server.

   ```
   $ mysql.server stop
   ```
3. and start your mysql server

   ```
   $ mysql.server start
   ```

   Starting MySQL
   SUCCEESS!
4. and start(or restart) your mysql server

   ```
   $ mysql.server start
   ```

   ```
   $ mysql.server restart
   ```

---

If you failed to start mysql server, please leave me error message when you run `mysql.server start`

Answer (score 1):

It may also be that the address to your sock-file is wrong in php.ini.

Open up the terminal, and run the following:

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql
```

This will show the correct path to your socket. Check it versus the address in php.ini. If it's wrong, then correct it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php edit the line 
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';
2. And the last thing $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql'; change this to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli'; Now restart your server. and see .

This problem might occur due to setting of a password to root thus phpmyadmin is not able to connect to the mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I fix this doing those followings commands

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
my_mac_password
```

Ctrl + Z

```
bg
```

Ctrl + D

quit the terminal

The problem is that I have to do this each time I reboot my mac.

Source: http://openclassrooms.com/courses/administrez-vos-bases-de-donnees-avec-mysql/installation-de-mysql