# MySql Error 2002 - Lion Server

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-error-2002

I have installed mysql on the lion server with the version 5.25a. I have also installed the mysql workbench. I have tried accessing the server through the terminal but to no avail as it says it is missing mysql.sock. I've browsed to the locations suchas /var/lib/mysql/ and /etc/my.cnf and there is nothing there at all! I believe this could be the problem, i have tried reinstalling, restarting and I have googled and googled and googled!

I really need some help with this one!

Comment: Have you looked into `/usr/local`? On my Lion system, the paths are `/tmp/mysql.sock` and `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`.

Comment: Also, is your server running yet? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933415/mysql-mac-error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-through-socket?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appeared to have made a severe error, I was using the 32-Bit version! Installed the 64 BIT, and then restarted the computer. The server started itself! MAGIC.