# Cannot get MySQL running in Terminal on macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, macos-sierra

I have been setting up a new laptop for development purposes and when trying to get MySQL to run in the Terminal I get the following message:

```
$ mysql -u root -p

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Can somebody please help me out here?

Comment: I've tried looking up answers from other posts but so far everything I have tried has failed.  When I looked at the my.conf file I found the information mysql listed as:

`[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket  = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 1M
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
tmpdir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/`

Comment: can upost whats inside mysql.socket ?

Comment: socket = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Also, I just tried running the mysql command again in terminal and now got this error:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Why are you using XAMPP? [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) is a much better tool for installing and managing databases like MySQL. XAMPP is intended for environments like Windows where that sort of thing is a giant pain to get working correctly. `brew install mysql` is not hard by comparison.

Comment: Im very new to using the command line and apparently I already have installed it as well via brew.  Could that be whats causing the problem?  How do I access mysql after installing it?

Comment: As you are using xampp can u access PHPMYADMIN ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Mac - Error 2002 - Can't connect to local... through socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933415/mysql-mac-error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-through-socket)

Comment: I have fixed it, it was due to multiple mysql instances installed.  Thank You all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You may get this error because mysql server is not started. For me it solved only by starting mysql server.

1. to start Mysql server (for Mac OS X), command line in terminal:

   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`
2. or, simply go to your Mac System Preference --> MySQL --> click on start mysql..